# VB Script to update existing number in existing text file

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I'm sure this is simple but my programming skills are next to none.

I have a text file that contains a number and always a number, e.g. `1`. I need a VBScript to always add `1` to that number in that text file, update, save, then close. The new file should contain `2`.

The next time I execute the script, the file should contain `3` and so on.

Comment: Can you please clarify VB.NET or VBScript?

Comment: Please show your best effort. As it stands now, you are just asking to write the whole code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I scraped together, assuming you meant VBScript and not VB.NET:

```
Option Explicit

Dim filename
filename = "C:\Path\To\Your\file.txt"

Dim fso, f, num

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1) ' for reading
num = CInt(f.ReadAll)
f.Close

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2) ' for writing
f.Write num + 1
f.Close
```

Keep in mind that there is no error handling in that code.

Comment: You're over-complicating things. `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") : num = CInt(fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)).ReadAll) : fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0), 2).Write num+1`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Agreed. I simplified my answer, but not to the level that you have in your comment. Given that the OP confesses next to no programming experience, I thought being slightly more verbose would be more helpful.

Comment: I've managed to get both solutions to work.  I just couldn't figure out how to add to a current file.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Bucks: I see you're new here -- if an answer gives you the solution you were looking for, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark outline next to it.